# C# "+" sign windows properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the class AppForm inherited Form with property AppIconForm (class).
I want at design time "+" sign appears on the edit IconForm property in the properties window and the child properties ( CloseIcon and MaximizedIcon ) appear. Thanks! :)

```
public partial class AppForm : Form
{
    AppIconForm iconform = new AppIconForm();
    public AppForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public AppIconForm IconForm
    {
        get { return iconform; }
        set { iconform = value; }
    }
}

//the code of AppIconForm class
public class AppIconForm
{
    Icon closeicon;
    Icon maximizeicon;
    public Icon CloseIcon
    {
        get { return closeicon; }
        set { closeicon = value; }
    }
    public Icon MaximizeIcon
    {
        get { return maximizeicon; }
        set { maximizeicon = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `+` for expanding properties which are themselves Types (like Font, Location) is provided by an `ExpandableObjectConverter`.

Comment: That's right, I could solve it Add  [ TypeConverter (typeof ( ExpandableObjectConverter ) ) ] to my class AppIconForm. Thanks Plutonix have fun day!

Answer (score 0):

Use [BrowsableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

```
[Browsable]
public Icon CloseIcon
{
  get { return closeicon; }
  set { closeicon = value; }
}
```

Comment: hmmm... did you actually try this? Regardless if it works or not (it doesn't), at a minimum, the `Browsable` attribute takes a parameter.